# How to delete specific word from string in mysql?

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench

I have string "this is my test string" and I want to remove only word "my".

The problem is word "my" will select from another query as

```
select word from table
```

I tried this if I know the word

```
set string = REPLACE(string,'my','');
```

So, any help

I want to do something like

```
 set string = REPLACE(string,select word from table,'');
```

my query is

```
set @test = 'this is my test query';  

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `test`;

CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE IF NOT EXISTS test(word longtext );

insert into test values('my');
insert into test values('test');

select replace(@test,(select word from test),'');
```

I have got error of sub query should returns 1 row

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`select replace(@test,word,'') from test`;

...

```
select @test:=replace(@test,word,'')  from test;
```

However keep in mind that you have multiple entries in the test table, @test will end up with all the words in table test replaced with ''. If that is what you want then all okay.

If you want a list output with @test with different words replaced use the first query and parse it in whatever you are passing the data to.

Comment: ok, but it doesn't change in the @test value
it just change in the appearance of it

Answer (score 1):

Maybe there's a better way but try this procedure

```
CREATE PROCEDURE myProc(IN teststring VARCHAR(255),
         OUT teststring_new varchar(255))
   BEGIN

      DECLARE n INT DEFAULT 0;
      DECLARE i INT DEFAULT 0;
      SELECT COUNT(*) FROM test INTO n;
      SET teststring_new = teststring;
      SET i=0;
      WHILE i<n DO 
        SELECT replace(teststring_new,(SELECT word FROM test LIMIT 1 OFFSET i),'') INTO teststring_new;
        SET i = i + 1;
     END WHILE;
     SELECT teststring_new;

END//
```

to call this

```
set @test = 'this is my test query';  

call myProc(@test, @outvalue)
```

Comment: No, this is not what I looking for

Answer (score 0):

I think the following will work in MySQL:

```
select @test = replace(@test, t.word, '')
from test t;
```

Do note that this works for a string in a variable.  It doesn't readily generalize to a column of such strings in a table.